# Thread safety of a int/long/referenceToAObject in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, java-threads, jvm-hotspot

Let say i have following code

```
int i =0;
setvalue(int i){this.i = i}
getvalue(){return i}
```

Now 200 thread calling `setValue` with random[a...b] number.
And 200 thread calling `getValue`

**Now what all values will be seen by thread calling getValue:**

1. Is it possible to see a value which is not in [a...b] set?
2. Is it guaranteed to see values only in set [a...b]? If yes some underlying info will be helpfull.
3. Behaviour is not defined by jvm?
4. Will the behaviour changes for long/ double/ String/ `referenceToAObject`?

EDIT:
I am interested in `referenceToAObject` , that is if instead of `int i`, we have `Object i` in above sample, So basic question is reference updation atomic in nature ?

Comment: For primitive `int`, no thread should ever see any intermediate value.  But, without synchronization, it is possible that some thread might get starved, and only see certain values.  `long` and `double` are _not_ guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what about referenceToObject

Comment: A reference is always an atomic value, i.e. will never appear to point to a wrong or illegal memory location, however, this does not apply to the object’s fields. For immutable objects like `String`, there is a guaranty that you will always see a fully constructed object, but for other objects, accessing it without proper synchronization can lead to an inconsistent state. You can see, reading or writing a reference is an atomic operation, but accessing the object behind it, is already a different operation.